# can someone explain what this php code is doing or its purpose

Tags: php

here is the snippit

```
$thisFile = str_replace('\\', '/', __FILE__);
$docRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$webRoot  = str_replace(array($docRoot, 'library/config.php'), '', $thisFile);
$srvRoot  = str_replace('library/config.php', '', $thisFile);
```

if i save this into test.php as a file. the section that im getting confused on is how the str_replace is makeing the $webRoot value come out to test.php

Answer (score 2):

That code will compute the absolute filesystem path (`$srvRoot`) and absolute URL path (`$webRoot`) to an application directory, I suppose, from where the current file can be addressed relatively with `library/config.php`.

[`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) is a magic constant and contains the absolute filesystem path to the file the constant is used in. `$thisFile` will contain that filesystem path where back-slashes are replaced by forward-slashes. `$docRoot` is the absolute filesystem path to the root directory that is accessible from the web.

So, for example, if `__FILE__` is `/var/www/htdocs/apps/foobar/library/config.php` and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is `/var/www/htdocs`, `$webRoot` is `/apps/foobar/` and `$srvRoot` is `/var/www/htdocs/apps/foobar/`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `__FILE__` is the name of the current source file, or "test.php".

Comment: That solves the mistery... sigh... Man, if you're going to post an answer, at least make it sound like one...